# adding values from a BigDecimal [ ]

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am struggling in finding a way to add up the values from a BigDecimal [ ] , which is obtained from a checkbox form out of a table from mysql.

This is the code I have so far, but I cannot find  a way to have just one number from those values obtained:

```
String select[] = request.getParameterValues("id"); 
if (select != null && select.length != 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) 
    {
        BigDecimal total[] = new BigDecimal [select.length];
        BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal("0.00");
        sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal [total.length]);

        out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated please.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Where exactly are the `BigDecimal` values you want to add? Are they the `String` values in the `select[]` array?

Comment: correct @JoãoSilva I get a String [] but I need to convert it to BigDecimals in order to get a sum up number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you are adding an array of `Strings` containing valid numbers you could do this:

```
BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) 
{
   sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal(select[i]));
}
out.println(sum);
```

The array `total[]` is pretty much redundant. You can move your `sum` declaration and `out.println(sum);` out of your loop.

Comment: Thanks @Reimeus but I get nothing on out.println(sum)

Comment: @Reimeus Your answer explains the way to add BigDecimal in loop, since BigDecimal is immutable, it will create many objects of BigDecimal. Is there any way we can do this without creating many objects?

Answer (score 4):

The reason it is not working is because you're not adding the contents that you've in your *select* array properly while creating your final *sum*. Something like this would work:

```
String select[] = request.getParameterValues("id"); 
if (select != null && select.length != 0)
{
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;   
    for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) 
    {
        try{
            sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal(select[i]));
        }catch(NumberFormatException nxe){
            //Handle your exception
        }
    }
   out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: I tried this @Sujay but I get nothing... I mean, no error, but nothing sum value is shown on the screen.

Comment: @Sheeyla: Consider checking the value that you get in your select[] array, also check whether any exception is getting thrown when you're trying to execute the `add(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks @Sujay... that was the issue... I tried your solution and also worked! many thanks to you too!